# htaccess Remove anything in the middle of URL (Thumbnail to Image src)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to convert thumbnails and image sources from:

```
domain.com/anyA-Z/anyA-Z-0-9/anyA-Z-0-9/directoryX/directoryY/anyA-Z-0-9.jpg
```

To

```
domain.com/directoryX/directoryY/anyA-Z-0-9.jpg
```

I wrote this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directoryX/directoryY/(.*)

RewriteRule ^domain.com/directoryX/directoryY/?$ domain.com/([a-zA-Z0-9|/\_]+)/directoryX/directoryY/$1 [L]
```

Any suggestion, why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain name is not part of the request URL path. In the `RewriteRule`, the pattern may be only part of the request URL, but you must match against the whole request URL path

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/directoryX/directoryY/(.+) /directoryX/directoryY/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, You made my day, Awesome! Olaf, based on what you wrote this is a broader rule I m going to use, Thanks: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+/directoryX/directoryY/(.+) /directoryX/directoryY/$1 [L]